# Check dr for value using if statement error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ado.net

I have a field in my db (access) that contains a value I need to change at display time. For example, if the initial value recieved from the db was "D" then I need to change it to say "Destroyed". I have tried using various if statements but cannot move forward owing to lack of programming knowledge. Option Strict disallows = and suggests Is.

I guess perhaps what I should be looking at is a switch statement. I say that because I may have to cycle through 12 different values before displaying. I have included the code that I have part completed and would be grateful if someone could help me to complete this. Many thanks.

```
While dr.Read()  
    lvRequests.Items.Add((dr(0)).ToString()).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
    lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(CDate(dr(5)).ToShortDateString())
    lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())

    With lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())
        If dr(3) Is "D" Then
            .dr(3) = "destroyed"
        Else
            If dr(3) Is "O" Then
                .dr(3) = "out"
            End If
        End If
    End With

    lvRequests.Items(lvRequests.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(9).ToString())    
    lvcount += 1  
End While
```

Comment: post code defining dr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try checking if any rows exist, this will prevent  `NullReferenceException`

```
 While dr.Read()  
   If dr.HasRows
   ...
   ...
```

this should be fine the way you had it, just change to use `ElseIf`

```
If dr(3) Is "D" Then
     dr(3) = "destroyed"
ElseIf dr(3) Is "O" Then
     dr(3) = "out"
End If
```

Comment: Scott it produces an error of Property 'item' is read only. item is a var that i declared outside the sub and not even sure why it is referencing this var.

Comment: I think this error is being produced because a datareader is read only. How would I use another method to achieve my goal. Thanks